# Swiper Slider - Display next/prev slide thumb with navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I am using Swiper Slider - 9.0.5

As in below screenshot, I am using swiper as homepage hero. With it's previous/next slide navigation, I also want to display small thumbnail of next/prev slide. I don't have any idea. Can anyone please help me out?

Navigation is working correctly. I just need help with displaying next/prev thumb image.

Thanks in advance!

[image]